# Django GeneratePDF with xhtml2pdf - Method not allowed (GET)

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf

I would modify the following  **class GeneratePDF** for rendering my template that is dynamically generated

In myproject/myapp/**utils.py**

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

**views.py**

```
class GeneratePDF(View):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    template = get_template('invoice.html')
    context = {
        "invoice_id": 123,
        "customer_name": "John Cooper",
        "amount": 1399.99,
        "today": "Today",
    }
    html = template.render(context)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('invoice.html', context)
    if pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %("123")
        content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
        download = request.GET.get("download")
        if download:
            content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        return response
    return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

I generate my template with the following:

```
class MyReport(ListView):
model = Reports
template_name = 'myreports.html' 
context_object_name = 'myreports'  
def get_context_data(self, *args,**kwargs):
    context = super(MyReport, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
    context['reports'] = Reports.objects.all().values('id','idsys','itemcode','ordercode').filter(id=self.kwargs['id'],idsys=self.kwargs['idsys'])
    return context
```

and I'm trying to generate PDF with the following class modified:

```
class GeneratePDF(View):
def get_context_data(self, *args,**kwargs):
    template = get_template('myreports.html')
    context = super(GeneratePDF, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
    context['reports'] = Reports.objects.all().values('id','idsys','itemcode','ordercode').filter(id=self.kwargs['id'],idsys=self.kwargs['idsys'])

    html = template.render(context)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('myreports.html', context)
    if pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "myreports_%s.pdf" %("1")
        content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
        download = request.GET.get("download")
        if download:
            content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        return response
    return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^reports_pdf/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<idsys>\d+)/$', views.GeneratePDF.as_view())
```

but I receive the **error**: Method not allowed (GET)
Have you any suggestions? Thank's

(I followed this: [Render_to_PDF_in_Django](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Guides/blob/master/all/Render_to_PDF_in_Django.md))

Answer (score 1):

You receiving this error because you inherited from `View` class which is not implemented `get()` method by default. This mean that your view don't know what to do with `GET` request, and raise the error. To resolve problem you need to define `get()` method for `GeneratePDF` class. Only after this `GeneratePDF` will be able to handle `GET` requests. Also `View` class doesn't provide `get_context_data` method, you can remove this `context = super(GeneratePDF, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)` and replace it with simple context definition as empty dictionary `context={}`:

```
class GeneratePDF(View):
    def get(self, *args,**kwargs):
        template = get_template('myreports.html')
        context = {}
        context['reports'] = Reports.objects.all().values('id','idsys','itemcode','ordercode').filter(id=self.kwargs['id'],idsys=self.kwargs['idsys'])

        html = template.render(context)
        pdf = render_to_pdf('myreports.html', context)
        if pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            filename = "myreports_%s.pdf" %("1")
            content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
            download = request.GET.get("download")
            if download:
                content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I tested it and I receive the followin errors:       A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide
the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
  "A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context "
Need a valid file name!
'<img src="/static/chart/img/mylogo-32.png"/>'
Need a valid file name!
'<img alt="en" class="flag-img" src="/static/chart/img/flags/en.png"/>'
'<img src="/static/wdbr_chart/img/favicon.ico"/>'
Obviously it is correctly generated in html format by class MyReport

Comment: @Mixo looks like you need provide `request` to the template also: `html = template.render(context, self.request)`.

Comment: @Mixo did you update `render_to_pdf` method accordingly?

Comment: @ neverwalkaloner I edited my post with the description of utils.py that contains the metod render_to_pdf

Comment: @Mixo you should add request to it also `def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}, request=None):` and inside it: `html  = template.render(context_dict, request)`.

Comment: @ neverwalkaloner: Done, I receive: 'context_dict' is not defined at line html = template.render(context_dict, request). Thank you for your patience and availability

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172893/discussion-between-neverwalkaloner-and-mixo).